# Programming constraints for a RTOS and a normal OS

Tags: operating-system, real-time, job-scheduling, rtos

This question has been bothering me from a long time, I tried to search online but didn't get any answer. I understand the difference between a normal OS and a RTOS. I wanted to understand what are the additional constraints (if any) imposed on an application programmer for a RTOS ?

For example I have some requirements and need to implement a solution which runs on a normal OS and an RTOS. What aspects should I take care when I am implementing the solution for the RTOS ? Should I profile my code to check the exact memory, processing requirements which I should give to the RTOS scheduler which will perform some feasibility analysis and determine if it can include my application in the existing schedule ?

Can some give me practical examples of how this is done in RTOS like OSE, Windriver etc ?

Comment: Read about [rate monotonic scheduling](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/beginner-s-corner/4023927/Introduction-to-Rate-Monotonic-Scheduling) and see if that helps with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most RTOS are thread schedulers rather than process schedulers, so there is only one "application" as such, made from multiple threads in a *single* process. In that context the issue of schedulability of your "application" is moot, since there is only one *application*.

If you have a non-realtime task (and it is perhaps implicit that this is the case if you are also able to run it on a general-purpose OS (GPOS), then on an RTOS you might run it at a low priority at a level shared by other non-realtime tasks with round-robin time-slicing enabled - those threads will then schedule in a similar manner to that of a GPOS.  Note that if one or more of these threads *never* yields, they must be run at the very lowest priority level possible, and in any case such behaviour would be generally undesirable - essentially such threads become the idle task.